# How Do I restore my computer's SSD to a new larger SSD?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, ssd, restore

I originally prepped the new Crucial 2 TB SSD in disk utility. I then removed the Mac 1 TB SSD from out of my MacBook Pro and put them both in my Aleratec duplicator. I proceeded to copy. This process seemed to work, however I had 1 TB of free space that was unaccessible. I was unable to move/add that space to the logical volume. I attempted to resize the logical volume but had -5341 error. Partition map to small. After several attempts at this I erased the new 2 TB SSD.

What type of partition or set up would I need to do to restore the Mac 1 TB SSD to the 2 TB SSD. And what process is recommended for doing so? Use the duplicator or restore in Disk Utility?

What I thought would be an easy upgrade is turning into nightmare. Does there need to be more then 1 partition on the 2 TB SSD?

Comment: If you had a 1TB SSHD in your MacBook Pro and you copied the data from that to your Crucial 2TB SSHD, doesn't that mean you'd then have 1TB of free space still on your Crucial 2TB SSHD? But the way I read your question, you're saying that having 1TB of free space means there was a problem? Obviously that's not the case, so you may need to clarify your question, as it seems a little unclear what the problem is/was?

Comment: Have you considered an alternative such as CarbonCopy Cloner? Most disk utilities will compensate for the larger drive when cloning, I've never had an issue. But a dedicated device that just does a straight bit for bit image might leave you with 1 TB unformatted space.

Comment: Monomeeth, After cloning the 1TB drive to the 2TB, the "extra space" was inaccessible. I tried to partition it. It failed, I tried to resizeStack and that failed with a -5341 error, map partition is to small. the logical volume is located in a virtual drive, (not my doing) I am wondering if that is an issue? I have a tech friend who usually does this for me. I will better try to post my questions.

Comment: Dr.Nixon, This is the first time I have tried this. I did not know ahead of time that there would/could be this issue. Had i, Yes I would have just bought the software to do it. But I typically like to try new things so I learn during the process. I also thought it would be easy. lol Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to repair the partition map. Disk utility only works within it's known partition maps. You disk duplicator probably didn't do it right. Instead, format the disk again and use disk utility to clone it. You can use the restore functionality for that.

Answer (score 0):

No. (And yes! see below?)

Very superficially spoken: A 2TB disk *can* hold only 1 partition occupying *all* available space. Technically: there are typically two more, small, partitions on a typical Apple setup: `EFI` for booting and `Recovery HD` for, well recovery.

So that is not the issue here. Partitions can very well be larger than 1TB for macOS.

The issue you see here is probably that the cloning was done not with high level Mac software like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/) or [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or something similar like [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org), but with a tool that starts on a deeper level, like [dd](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html) or [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org).

That means that the old, smaller partition got duplicated – with its size information – to the new driv; leaving you with witnessing a large chunck of unused space on that drive.

To remedy this situation you can either *resize* the now used partition to grow to the desired size – over the unused free space –  using `/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility` or [`gparted`](https://gparted.org) or [Stellar Partition Manager](http://stellar-info.com/partition-manager.php).

If none of the tools in the paragraph above are available it is still possible to clone – not the old drive, as an image, but the *contents* of the  old drive – to the new drive; formatted to your liking.

Since Disk Utility got severely crippled in newer versions of OS X/macOS the recommendation for inexperienced users would have to go to some kind of third party tool like Carbon Copy Cloner.